# Inconsistent sub title - is it even needed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Once you are in your job listings on the right hand side are some sub sections such as **Your Recent Searches**.  Above that is a **back to listings** section.

Is this really needed as a sub section as it simply will always contain the one link to return to search results.  Maybe this could be eliminated entirely with a single link at the top / bottom stating to return to search results.

As it stands its casing is different than all other sub sections as it is all in lower case and I just feel that once you've gone to the say end of your favorites list its natural to have a link there "return to search results".
[image]